# datarow css class - determining the number of row returned in a table - clarification

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am kind of new to html, css, jquery and javascript

I am trying to see how many rows have been returned based on the search .
below is the code in the javascrip that I am using .

**key notes**

Table name : searchResultsTable

```
var numberOfrows = $("#searchResultsTable tr").length;
```

**Problem**

The table is actually returning one row, but when I try to print the `numberofrows`
it is printing as 2 . not sure why.
Depending upon the number of reports, I have to call different function.

I checked the code to see if there is any hidden row but nothing.
Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: First, you should work on [accepting answers to some of your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to encourage people to help you in the future.

Comment: Sounds like you  have a table header in the first row.

Comment: @Blazemonger Will sure do that in Future.

Comment: You dont have to wait for the future.. if you go to your profile and to the questions tab, you can still find the old questions. If they were answered, click the check-mark left of the answer to accept them.

Comment: @SvenBieder Thanks for the quick response . I looked into the table and found that I have placed the TH inside <TR> . Like <tr>  <th> heading name  </tr> Not sure if that will get counted as table row .

Comment: @DamienOvereem I am kind of new to StackOverflow .I have marked as Answered

Comment: @MattPatt yes that counts as row

Comment: It is best practice for SO to post your code somewhere so people can see exactly what you are doing. Please try to setup an example on ie. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sure will do that . Thanks for the info - Damien

Comment: @SvenBieder You my man . Thanks . I tried my example in jsfiddle . It worked.Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of SvenBieder . 
 table header in the first row will also be counted when you try to count the number of rows in a table.

Comment: If you're using a `<thead>` around your table header, then you can reference `#searchResultsTable tbody tr` instead of just `#searchResultsTable tr` to get the remaining rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have as first row your table headers included.
That means .length returns your amount of datarows +1 for the headerrow.